# Customize Access Request emails and functionality

Tags: custom, access

Is it possible to customize the access request emails.

also another question is if I can customize this functionality, we want to keep a track of have requested access in a list for example? Is there a hidden list for this?

My users are also requesting to be able to answer an email to the user once its accepted or rejected the access.  Is it possible from sharepoint not from outlook?

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe John is correct if you are limited to Out-of-the-box solutions but there is another option if custom code is available to you.  [Create your own application page](http://mindstick.com/Articles/6345ba2f-1a8b-4ccf-9c81-d656ea0b4bf2/?Custom%20Application%20Page%20in%20SharePoint) to handle Access Requests and have it generate the email in whatever format you want.  Since you would be creating this email in your own code, you would control all addresses used so you could easily allow direct replies to the person who requested access.

[This post](https://soderlind.no/customize-out-of-the-box-application-pages-accessdenied-confirmation-error-login-requestaccess-signout-webdeleted/) explains how to tell SharePoint to use your page instead of the default.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't anyway to customize the access request emails or how the functionality of such works.