# Customizing the Access Request Email text in SharePoint O365

Tags: administration, access, office-365

SharePoint Online (O365) has default Access Request settings on configuring which with a Site Owner's email address, he gets a mail in his mailbox with an option to **Accept/Decline** the site access request. Is this possible to change this default e-mail format and instead of redirecting to the Access Request list, having an option to **add some custom text and provide a hyperlink to some other webpage**?

Please throw some light on this topic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email content is getting generated from inside the code. So it's not an option to change the content.

In case of on premise we can probably create a new page in layout an use it. But in your case this will not work.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/apurdon/archive/2008/01/30/can-you-customise-the-request-access-email.aspx

[Customize Access Request emails and functionality](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28901/customize-access-request-emails-and-functionality)

Comment: Couldn't they create a custom Access denied application page (with it's own email sending functionality )via Provider Hosted app and use this page instead? Just asking as I am fairly new to app development model and so far I have always thought things like application pages and event receivers would go into the provider-hosted apps to use in cloud.

Comment: This is not the access denied page. It's the access request feature. Also if I remember custom access denied page is configured via central admin?

Comment: custom accessdenied is configured by a powershell command.